# Creating multiple sheets with input function in xlsxwriter python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlsxwriter, worksheet-function, worksheet

I want to create multiple sheets using the `input` function. I used the `split` function, but still it only creates one sheet. The idea is not to be restricted by the number of sheets.

```
import xlsxwriter
from xlsxwriter import workbook

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('doc.xlsx')

sheetnames = input("Enter value: ").split(', ')

sheetss = []
for i in sheetnames:
  sheetss.append(i)
worksheet_data = workbook.add_worksheet(i)

workbook.close()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the `workbook.add_worksheet(i)` inside the `for` loop?

Comment: no, workbook.add_worksheet(i) is outside the for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("test.xlsx")
sheetnames = input("Enter value: ").split(", ")
for i in sheetnames:
    workbook.add_worksheet(i)
workbook.close()
```

Using `split()` already creates a list so you don't need another variable to hold the sheetnames.

Comment: Thanks, it is working, but when I add data, only puts it in last sheet. What to do to put same data in every sheet?

Comment: @project.py - Depends what kind of data you're adding. See [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_data.html). You can ask a *new* question if you can't figure it out.